# I want to hide my navbar (ul) when links in the navbar are clicked. How to do that? Here’s the code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I click the link of navbar on mobile view, its overriding with content and ul is not collapsing.  I want to hide my navbar (ul) when links in the navbar are clicked. How to fix this issue? Please help.

Here’s the code:

```
    <nav>
      <div class="navbar" >
      <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check">
      <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
      <label class ="logo">B</label>
      <ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#Home" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about-me">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
<li><a href="#projects-completed">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    </nav>
/* css*/
nav{
   
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    height: 57px;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
}

label.logo{
    color: white;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0px 11px;
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-radius: 11px;
    margin-left: 39px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

nav ul{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 94px;
    

}

nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: bolder;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 7px 13px;
}
a.active, nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(199, 130, 255);
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.checkbtn{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-right: 40px;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: none;
}

   #check{
    display: none;
   }
 
/*for navbar responsiveness*/
@media (max-width: 952px){

    label.logo{
        font-size: 30px;
       
    }
nav ul li a{
    font-size: 13px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 858px){

.checkbtn{
    display: block;
    
}
ul{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #1f1d27;
    top: 61px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
}


nav ul li{
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

nav ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
}

a:hover, a.active{
    background: none;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    border-radius: 2px;

}

#check:checked ~ ul{
   left: 0;
}

nav ul li a:active {
left: 0;
transition: all .5s;
}
}
```

Whenever I click the link of navbar on mobile view, its overriding with content and ul is not collapsing.  I want to hide my navbar (ul) when links in the navbar are clicked. How to fix this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the script for whenever you click the navbar, and adding the class style to the `ul`

check this video for the evidence :D
[video](https://www.loom.com/share/08f52ca5ae0b4137bf9bbe922ed86f0d)

```js
 const navtabs = document.querySelectorAll('a')
    const ul = document.querySelector('ul')
    for( let i = 0; i < navtabs.length;i++){
      navtabs[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        ul.classList.add('clicked')
      })
    }
```

```css
nav {
      background-color: rebeccapurple;
      height: 57px;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
    }

    label.logo {
      color: white;
      font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Arial Narrow Bold", sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 60px;
      padding: 0px 11px;
      border: 4px solid white;
      border-radius: 11px;
      margin-left: 39px;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    nav ul {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 94px;
    }

    nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 60px;
    }

    nav ul li a {
      color: white;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-size: bolder;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
      padding: 7px 13px;
    }
    a.active,
    nav ul li a:hover {
      background-color: rgb(199, 130, 255);
      border-radius: 3px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .checkbtn {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: white;
      float: right;
      line-height: 60px;
      margin-right: 40px;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: none;
    }

    #check {
      display: none;
    }

    /*for navbar responsiveness*/
    @media (max-width: 952px) {
      label.logo {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      nav ul li a {
        font-size: 13px;
      }
    }

    @media (max-width: 858px) {
      .checkbtn {
        display: block;
      }
      ul {
          /* idk in my code this possition is not working,and then i comment this style */
        /* position: fixed; */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #1f1d27;
        top: 61px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all 0.5s;
      }

      nav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin: 30px 0;
        line-height: 30px;
      }

      nav ul li a {
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      a:hover,
      a.active {
        background: none;
        background-color: rebeccapurple;
        border-radius: 2px;
      }

      #check:checked ~ ul {
        left: 0;
      }

      nav ul li a:active {
        left: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s;
      }

    /* you can create new style for to add in the ul */
      .clicked{
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" />
      <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
      <label class="logo">B</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about-me">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects-completed">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```